I am creating a login page for my website and am getting the 405 error (Method not allowed). I think it is due to an incorrect server configuration
The issue is with the POST method. I have three files which are handling this procedure, and one database. They are named login.html, server.js, and authroutes.js. Here is the relevant code in login.html:
<div class="login-container">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form id="loginForm" class="login-form" action="/auth/login" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" required>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        
            <script>
                async function submitLoginForm(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default form submission behavior
    
                    const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
                    const formData = new FormData(form);
    
                    try {
                        const response = await fetch('/auth/login', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: formData,
                        });
    
                        console.log('Response status:', response.status);
    
                        if (response.ok) {
                            // Redirect to the profile page on successful login
                            console.log('Login successful. Redirecting to profile page.');
                            window.location.href = '/profile';
                        } else {
                            // Handle unsuccessful login (e.g., display an error message)
                            console.error('Login failed');
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error during login:', error);
                    }
                }
    
                // Add an event listener to the form submit event
                document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', submitLoginForm);
            </script>

Here is the code for server.js:
//server.js

// Import necessary modules
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const authRoutes = require('./authroutes');

// Create an Express application
const app = express();
const port = 5500;

// Use body-parser middleware to parse POST request data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Middleware function to log parsed request body
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Parsed request body:', req.body);
  next();
});


// Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Use authentication routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

// Set up MySQL connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'login',
});

// Handle any errors during MySQL connection
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database');
});

// Set up the server to listen on the specified port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


and here is the authroutes.js file:
// authRoutes.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Create a MySQL connection pool
const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'login',
});

// Handle login POST request
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Query the database for the user
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    const [rows] = await db.execute(query, [username]);

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      res.status(401).send('User not found');
      return;
    }

    const user = rows[0];
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (match) {
      // Password is correct, login successful
      res.redirect('/profile/'); // Redirect to the profile page
    } else {
      // Password is incorrect
      res.status(401).send('Invalid password');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during login:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// Export the router
module.exports = router;

I've tried changing the port number to 3306 in server.js, where mysql database is hosted. But my website is hosted on port 5000. Is this the reason, and how do I fix this? I am using Visual Studio Code.

Still having this issue, any guidance would be appreciated!
